# library linked but Xcode says "file not found."

Tags: ios, xcode

This just started happening with my project and I have no idea what to do.

I've been using the Parse framework and everything has been fine so far.  But now, even though the library is included:

[image]

and linked:

[image]

I still get a "'Parse/Parse.h' file not found" error when I import it into classes.  Even weirder (at least to me), the project still builds and runs.  When I build or clean the project, the warning disappears, but then it reappears right away.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6):

For all who have  not found issue:

1. Go to Build settings and search for "Framework Search Paths", then remove everything and put ./ and make it recursive (by double-clicking on it)
2. IMPORTANT - Don't download Parse framework on Windows and then copy to Mac! inside framework there are some links and while copying they get corrupted. Download the framework directly from Mac and when added to xcode make sure it has "Headers" folder under it in XCode frameworks.

I hope it helps some people.

Comment: Point 2 tripped me up. Cheers

Comment: adding one more point to above answer. we have to do that both in project and target settings.. for me adding ./ and making recursive only in target settings dint help, so i had done same thing in project setting as well, this time it worked ..

Comment: But i dint get why to make it recursive.. what happens when we make it recursive can anyone explain?

Comment: @RockandRoll If your framework is in the directory I don't think you need it to be recursive, i.e. specifying `path/to/dir` in `Framework Search Paths` and your framework is `path/to/dir/MyCustom.framework`.  Choosing `Levels` rather than `Combined` when looking at Build Settings might help clarify what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by changing the #import "Parse/Parse.h" to #import ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--just "#import", with nothing actually imported?

Comment: have you checked by changing the "inverted commas" to this <> like #import <Parse/Parse.h>

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will search for the header files in a special search path. In your case, it seems that the file "Parse/Parse.h" is not in your compiler's header file search path. Check this in your compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

How many targets do you have? If more than one, maybe the debug target doesn't include the framework.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem when I use the demo called "TodoTable", and I solve this by deleting the link in `target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Parse.framework`, and then, adding it again. You may do it by clicking `+` button, and choosing `Add other...`, then, in the project folder, you can find the `Parse.framework` file. After that, rebuilding your project, and it will be ok.