# Xcode Library included but not found?

Tags: ios, xcode, shared-libraries, wikitude

I'm working with Wikitude AR and on running their out-of-the-box example I'm running into an error.

**Error:**

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x12008d088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

**Output:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/WikitudeNativeSDK.framework/WikitudeNativeSDK
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/F826D5F6-554F-4CFA-B3DA-D3522636E93A/unityexample.app/unityexample
Reason: image not found
```

Here's a screen of the included library: *I've also tried re-adding it*

[image: library included xcode]

So why is this framework not found?

Already tried: [library linked but Xcode says "file not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928174/library-linked-but-xcode-says-file-not-found)

*Xcode 7.3.1 | OS X 10.11.4*

## Solution

In newer versions of Xcode / iOS you need to do the additional step of adding the framework as an `Embedded Binary`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469804/332578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try enabling the following: [image]

If that doesn't work then best will to go through the example app supplied by the framework provider or check the documentation page aginan. It seems they have lot of dependancy frameworks to be added for it to work:
http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

1. Delete the framework by right click show in finder
2. Do a clean build Cmd+Shift+K
3. Then create a new build.

Which XCode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 - I tried your solution and it seemed like it was going to work but the app eventually crashes with the same output.